# PHP FTP login process is so slow on our new server

Tags: php, apache, ftp

We are in the process of migrating to a new server. We are using the same version of php on both the new and old servers with very similar settings. Our application uses the php ftp functions to connect to a remote ftp and upload files to it from our server.

The problem I am finding is that the new server is so much slower than the old one at uploading the files. I have done numerous tests with multiple large and small files and I have narrowed it down to the ftp_connect and ftp_login php functions (the process of transferring the file is very quick on both servers). On the old server this log in process takes a fraction of a second (~0.2seconds), however on the new server it takes about 5 seconds.

Can anyone suggest to me if there is a php setting or a server setting that might be causing the ftp login to take so much longer?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The keyword is probably "Reverse Lookups" or "Reverse DNS". I don't know which FTP server you are using but you should disable this. For proftpd this would be

```
UseReverseDNS off
IdentLookups off
```

in the config.

Comment: Is this not the settings required on the ftp server we are connecting to rather than the client (our server)?

Comment: these settings have to be done on the server machine, of course.

Comment: Yes so this can't be the issue since both my old server and new server (read this as the client connections) are making an ftp connection to the same third party ftp server and my new server is a lot slower at connecting than the old server. Hope that makes sense!

Comment: .. Which may be caused by not having a proper reverse DNS entry, or not running identd - which these two statements will solve. There may also be different firewalling, making the first server work with active connections, while the other have to fall back to a passive connection.